# Mongodb not connecting after insert with python

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Im making a python API and making some inserts , suddenly i cant connect to mongo anymore

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-19T07:16:16.067-0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-07-19T07:16:16.068-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Any idea on what could be causing this? my ubuntu

Comment: See this, is a similar issue: [thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mongo-no-longer-connects)

Comment: To summarize the thread mentioned by @Tuxpilgrim, the `mongod` process was killed by the OOMkiller due to lack of memory in the server. This is usually a sign of an underprovisioned hardware. You can check the system logs for signs of the OOMkiller. If this is true, then you can: 1) give the server more RAM, 2) configure swap.